# Вычитание чисел для календаря --> "2015-03-22" - 14 = "2015-03-08"

Tags: html, javascript

Как в Javascript создать "Калькулятор" для календаря следующим образом:

> ПРИМЕР:
>
> '2015-03-22' - 14 = '2015-03-08'
>
> '2015-03-08' - 14 = '2015-02-22' <<< Т.к. в феврале 28 дней
>
> '2015-01-10' - 14 = '2014-12-27'

У меня будет использоваться только одно действие '- 14' (вычесть 14). Данная команда будет активироваться через `function ()` после нажатия на кнопку (button onclick="func();").

Comment: http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates-in-javascript.html#fbid=6_7gbE6tZtd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начните  с классических примеров - http://learn.javascript.ru/datetime

Там прямо открытым текстом не говориться "вычитайте даты так", но там есть способ, который это рассказывает.

Но вот [здесь](http://javascript.ru/forum/misc/1534-vychitanie-daty.html) прям Ваш случай разбирается.